# Cosmos DB stored procedure: how to get the partition name where it is running?

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

I would like to build queries inside my stored procedure, but as they need to be scoped to a single partition, I would need to build a SQL like:

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM p WHERE p.partition_key = '" + variableWithPartitionKey + "'";
```

I think the partition name should be available as a property somewhere, in the Context object or something like it, but couldn't find it to populate **variableWithPartitionKey**.
Can anyone point me on the right direction?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know the partition key property when writing stored procedures for a container. There is no mechanism in stored procedures to tell you what that is. In the stored procedure function declaration you will need to pass in the partition key value and any other data to process as a parameter to the stored procedure. You can learn more about stored procedures here [How to write stored procedures, triggers, and user-defined functions in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-write-stored-procedures-triggers-udfs)